# Why do I have to double-click on my button to make the event work?

Tags: javascript, html

Is simple, i'm starting with javascript. I wrote down an example for the 'removeChild' method, with simple function that activates with a button. But, I have to double-click on it to make it works.

I guess that this could be solved using JQuery, but I just want to understand what's happening, and try to figure out what is javascript understanding.

This is my HTML:

```js
function remove() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("demo");
  var child = parent.lastChild;
  parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
<button onClick="remove()">Erase last</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) includes text nodes. Because you have a line-break after the last `<p>`, your first click actually *removes the line-break*. The subsequent click removes the `<p>` element.

To demonstrate, take a look at this example, where I've simply removed the line-breaks from your HTML:

```js
function remove() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("demo");
  var child = parent.lastChild;
  parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p><p>Paragraph 3</p></div>
<button onClick="remove()">Erase last</button>
```

However, removing line-breaks from your HTML is hardly a practical solution!

Instead, replace `lastChild` with [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/lastElementChild):

```js
function remove() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("demo");
  var child = parent.lastElementChild;
  parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
<button onClick="remove()">Erase last</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

With parent.childNodes you can find all child nodes of the div

```
NodeList(6) [text, p, text, p, text, p]
```

Click every twice you can remove a p element.

Not double-click.

Reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes